# Why does this function never terminate?

Tags: java, multithreading, deadlock

Why does the following function deadlock? In other words, why does it prevent anyone from obtaining, not only the write lock, but the read lock? Can't read locks be shared?

```
    void testReadWriteLock() throws InterruptedException {
        final ReentrantReadWriteLock lock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();

        // Other thread acquires read lock and never releases it.
        new Thread(() -> lock.readLock().lock()).start();
        Thread.sleep(100);

        // Other thread attempts (and fails) to acquire write lock.
        new Thread(() -> lock.writeLock().lock()).start();
        Thread.sleep(100);

        lock.readLock().lock(); // This blocks forever
    }
```

Comment: "Other thread attempts (and fails) to acquire write lock" does it fail, or does it merely block waiting to acquire the lock?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered an interesting property of `ReentrantReadWriteLock`: any attempt to acquire the write lock (even blocking) blocks all subsequent attempts to acquire read locks (except re-entrant attempts). At least, that's the case in Oracle's 1.8 JVM. There is a certain logic in prioritizing writes: it ensures that data is up-to-date.

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple threads obtain the read lock, but when the write lock is obtained, everyone else is blocked out. Since you never unlock anything, the final lock call in the method will never obtain the lock.